# How to update linux ubuntu 14.04 to 15.04?

Tags: 14.04, updates

I am using ubuntu linux 14.04 along side with Windows XP. How to update this version to 15.04 linux ? I don't know whether if I directly download Ubuntu linux 15.04 from ubuntu site , Will my windows  will be affected ?
I just want to update to 15.04 alongside XP.

Answer (score 4):

Open a terminal and fire the command:

```
sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
sudo nano /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
```

Change `lts` to `normal`:

```
Prompt=normal
```

Start the upgrade:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

---

Windows remains untouched.

Answer (score 1):

Go to **Software & Update** ---> **Updates**(3rd option) ---> Change notify me of a new Ubuntu Version from **For Long-term support** to **any version**

[image]

Comment: I have already did that

Comment: Reboot your machine. It should show upgrades.

Comment: Then search the dash for update